# XSLT: get xml element when 2 conditions matches

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Aim is merging 3 files into one file.

In first step, I got 2 vars from first 2 files.

The 3rd file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-15"?><BeraterInnen>
   <Berater>
      <mitarbeiter_id>1234</mitarbeiter_id>
      <berater_id>5551</berater_id>
      <fk_oe_id>2222</fk_oe_id>
      <Berater_Name>John Doe</Berater_Name>
   </Berater>
   <Berater>
      <mitarbeiter_id>1234</mitarbeiter_id>
      <berater_id>5552</berater_id>
      <fk_oe_id>3333</fk_oe_id>
      <Berater_Name>John Doe</Berater_Name>
   </Berater>
   ...cut..
```

As you can see, mitarbeiter_id is the same but for fk_oe_id = 2222 and fk_oe_id = 3333, I get different berater_id. Therefore, I can't

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$Berater[fk_oe_id = $var1]/berater_id"/> or
 <xsl:value-of select="$Berater[mitarbeiter_id = $var2]/berater_id"/> or
```

Note: $Berater is doc()

I need these berater_id and berater_name from that node matches fk_oe_id = var1 **AND** mitarbeiter_id = var2.

thanks in advance,
 Celal

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? -- Please clarify; "*Note: $Berater is doc()*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Berater[fk_oe_id = $var1 
and 
mitarbeiter_id = $var2]/berater_id"/>
```

?